# Black screen in Genymotion

Tags: android, genymotion

My Genymotion installation is unable to start my virtual devices. The same virtual devices starts properly in VirtualBox. Only **black screen** with button on right side appears in Genymotion. Buttons works (opens dialogs) and emulator is connected to adb and I'm able to start applications from Eclipse.

[image: Genymotion]

Comment: checkout this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547907/genymotion-stays-on-black-screen-when-loading-emulator/39547908#39547908

Answer (score 3):

Your network adapter can be misconfigured:
Edit the Host-only Network that is listed in the network category of the File/preferences menu of VirtualBox.
The adapter's IP address has to be in the same network (192.168.56.0/24 by default) as DHCP server's IP address and DHCP's IP address bounds. If all those addresses are not in the same network, then your Genymotion virtual device might not be able to start.
You can also remove the Host-only Network. Genymotion will recreate it automatically at the next virtual device start.

Your firewall can block the application
Please check your firewall rules

You can check the log files (see FAQ about Does the Genymotion application produce log files to help me understand a functionnal problem?) to see if an error occured.
If no error is present, then try to restart your virtual device directly from the VirtualBox application.

---

that what i find in the Genymotion faq, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be the graphic driver. I am still trying to figure out the exact reason. Meanwhile try the following:
These commands print out the configuration of a Ubuntu machine:

```
$ date && lsb_release -sd || cat /etc/*release && uname -s -r && \
unity --version && /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p && dpkg -s mesa-utils
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues with Genymotion 2.0.1 and Virtualbox 4.3.4 on Ubuntu 12.04 machine.

If you haven't solve this issue and if it is not caused by misconfiguration you can try toggling to full screen mode on the emulator's window and see if the graphics will load and make this awful black screen disappears. This solved mine problems (after 1 day of re-installing different versions of both Genymotion and VirtualBox :) )

Found this workaround [here on Google+ GenymotionEmulator](https://plus.google.com/+GenymotionEmulator/posts/Ww6RgkEdi5n).

I think Genymotion's team is aware of this and are working on it.

Answer (score 0):

For me updating genymotion and virtual to their latest version solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and struggled to solved the issue. However it does not solved maybe it takes much time and effort to solve the problem. My suggestion is that give up using genymotion and try its alternatives such as bluestacks, droid4x etc.