# genymotion stays on black screen when loading emulator

Tags: crash, emulation, genymotion, freeze

When i start a new virtual device with genymotion sometimes it will get stuck on the black screen and not load. Sometimes it will work especially just after a restart, otherwise it will hang on the black screen and become unusable.
[image: black genymotion loading screen]

Comment: i have same probblem. if i disable network in virtual box and run in virtual box, the device not stuck anymore. but when run with genymotion the network active again

Answer (score 10):

If the emulator freezes or crashes this is likely due to incompatability with your video card driver.

If however it just hangs on the black screen, this can be due to two reasons:

---

**Your Firewall or other program is blocking genymotion**

If this is likely the case then try **disconnecting any vpn services** or other software which could be hindering this, and ensuring that genymotion is able to connect to the virtual device over the local network.

If you have a firewall, make sure that you allowed connections to the Genymotion network, set to 192.168.56.0/24 by default.

---

**Your network adaptor is misconfigured**

If this is the case you should try the following

1. Run VirtualBox.
2. Open File > Preferences > Network (or VirtualBox > Preferences for Mac OS X).
3. Edit the Host-only Network by clicking .
4. Check that the adapter IPv4 address is in the same network (192.168.56.0/24 by default) as the DHCP server address, lower address bound and upper address bound. If not, your virtual device cannot start.

You can also remove the Host-only Network by clicking . Genymotion will automatically recreate it at the next virtual device start.

Comment: The issue was resolved after disabling my VPN connection; I wish the feedback from the emulator was something a little better than just a black screen.

Comment: For some reason, mine was set to 192.168.56.1/24 - After changing to zero it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem in Windows 10 after I updated to VirtualBox 6.0.4 and Genymotion 3.0.1. I am using 2nd generation core i5 cpu (i5 2400). Update to this graphics card is not available. According to the official documentation:

```
Your graphics card no longer matches Genymotion requirements. Please see https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#supported-graphics-cards.
If you are using a dual graphics card laptop (e.g. Intel/Nvidia or Intel/AMD), make sure you are using the most recent/powerful one.
```

https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#virtual-device-window-empty

Only solution to my problem was keep the VirtualBox 6.0.4 but downgrade genymotion to 2.12.2 version because my graphics cards is no longer supported and only supported intel graphics card is intel hd graphics 4000 generation. Link to Genymotion 2.12.2 is below:

https://dl.genymotion.com/releases/genymotion-2.12.2/genymotion-2.12.2.exe

Answer (score 1):

Following the below steps solved the issue for me.

1. Open Windows Settings > Network & Internet > Change adapter options
2. Right-click on VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
3. Select Disable
4. Right-click on the VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter again and Select Enable

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Press power button doesn't start until then they will stuck on android logo screen then restart

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Windows. updating the video card driver solved the issue.
Genymotion 3.0.1
VirtualBox 6.0.4

Comment: how you solved?

Comment: @Nbn, Yes. As I said: **updating the video card driver solved the issue**

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue in 2 steps:

1. Check the Android API versions installed on your system from \SDK\platforms directory.
2. Create New AVD using available Android versions only.

Answer (score -1):

You need to **check** 4 different things:

1. proxy connections to be off( *Gennymotion/setting/Network*)
2. SDK be set( *Gennymotion/ABD/SDK*)
3. Graphic card driver be successfully installed
4. Virtual box installed and working correctly

> Try again please. hope you will fix it easily.