# Genymotion is waiting at "booting"

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

Genymotion is waiting at "booting".
Screen stays black.

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @RohitMandiwal This has a solution on it posted by Howard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55233869/genymotion-still-waiting-at-booting

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing the cache of Genymotion.
**Settings > Misc > Clear Cache**

Comment: Continue on booting. :(

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39547908/8470239) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21486549/8470239) also

Comment: @hazz-rush solved, close genymotion and all virtual box, on the terminal type:

    adb kill-server and adb start-server