# Genymotion Still waiting at "Booting"

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I use Genymotion for Android Studio but genymotion still booting does not On status

I searched for a solution and followed

- Uninstall and Re-install
- Clear Cache
- Remove device and new install
- Fix Host-Only Ethernet to default
- And another thing to try

But I can't fix it

> Genymotion v3.0.1
>
> VM VirtualBox v6.0.4

Please help me find a solution. Help me.

Sorry for my english

[image: here]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tried to reset cache, re-create the device, toggle network mode, upgrade Genymotion to 3.0.1, and NONE of them worked.

A temp fix to change "booting" status to "on":

1. Open `Genymotion Shell`
2. run `devices list`
3. then run in a new terminal `adb connect [DEVICE IP]:5555`

Comment: Had the exact same issue and this fixed it. Going to see what the core issue is, because I'd rather not run this everytime I start an emulator.

Comment: it says connected.
but when I run adb devices it doesn't show any thing

Answer (score 8):

Looks, like this is some adb or Genymotion bug. To solve this, you must manually connect adb to running Genymotion Device In first, you need to know Androids internal IP. You can find it in window title of Genymotion device. Next:

cd to your Android SDK dir

`cd to platform-tools
./adb connect 192.168.57.102:5555`

where 192.168.57.102 is my IP address of Genymotion Virtual Device. You must put here your own

Answer (score 5):

I killed the running adb process in task manager and the status of the genymotion device changes from booting to on. Finally the genymotion emulator can now be recognized.

Answer (score 3):

just go to Control Panel\NetworkandInternet\Network Connections just c to that virtual host-only network is enabled and disable other duplicate virtual host-network which are with "#" and try to start again. It works for me

Comment: That was my last hope and it worked.
Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run genymotion as administrator. It worked for me.
But then you will not be able to add files to the emulator by using drag & drop feature.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

- make sure there are no adb servers running. Use the command adb kill-server to kill any running server.
- set Genymotion to Use Genymotion Android tools (default)

See: https://docs.genymotion.com/latest/Content/02_Application/Configuring_Genymotion/ADB.htm

This work for me.

I am very happy to be able to solve this problem, I can't work for 2 days with this problem.

Comment: Interesting, it actually work for Intellij 2019 and Flutter

Comment: @VictorTong It's not that interesting you can't really say it works with those.Those work with adb.And you're fixing adb so you can't say android studio or any other ide that uses adb won't work.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason for the occurrence of this error is due to the difference in adb versions in the development machine and the connected connected device/emulator being used for debugging.

So resolution is:

Firstly disconnect device/emulator.

Run on terminal/command prompt following commands:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

This will start the adb successfully. Now you can connect device. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Tryed solutions but none worked for me.

At the end run the genymotion as a administrator, now it's work for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case:

1. Go to the virtual box
2. Right-click on tools => host manager network
3. Remove all virtual network adapters
4. Run Genymotion emulator

Comment: that's the solution that saved my morning